# flash object not displaying in safari

Tags: ruby-on-rails, flash, safari, cross-browser

I have a flash object embedded in my website with the embed code that I got from a website. It does not show up in Safari, it's just a blank area where the flash object is supposed to be. What can I do to get the object to show up in Safari? Thanks.

Here is the embedded code:

```
<object classid="clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000" codebase="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=9,0,0,0" height="250" width="258" id="sn_player" align="middle">
 <param name="allowFullScreen" value="true" />
<param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always" />
<param name="wmode" value="transparent" />
<param name="allownetworking" value="all" />
<param name="bgcolor" value="#000000" />
<param name="movie" value="http://sermonplayer.com/swf/player45.swf">
<PARAM name="flashvars" value="file=http://sermonplayer.com/build_xml_wzd_sn.php?player=12031-recent-.xml&skin=http://sermonplayer.com/swf/modieus_arial_ond.swf&backcolor=#111111&frontcolor=#2ea0aa&lightcolor=#2ea0aa&=Save&player_name=name (no punctuation)&controlbar=bottom&autostart=false&displayclick=play&icons=true&mute=false&repeat=none&shuffle=false&stretching=fill&plugins=&viral.onpause=false" />
<embed src="http://sermonplayer.com/swf/player45.swf" quality="high" height="250" width="260" id="sn_player" align="middle" allowScriptAccess="always" allowfullscreen="true" bgcolor="#000000" wmode="opaque" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" flashvars="file=http://sermonplayer.com/build_xml_wzd_sn.php?player=12031-recent-.xml&skin=http://sermonplayer.com/swf/modieus_arial_ond.swf&backcolor=#000000&frontcolor=#888888&lightcolor=#2ea0aa&=Save&player_name=name (no punctuation)&controlbar=bottom&autostart=false&displayclick=play&icons=true&mute=false&repeat=none&shuffle=false&stretching=fill&plugins=&viral.onpause=false" pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer">
 </embed></object><a href="http://www.sermonplayer.com" border="01">  <img src="http://www.sermonplayer.com/images/poweredby.gif" border="0" height="1px" width="1px"></a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested it in my safari browser in a clean rails app and it worked just fine. I'm using safari 5.2.1, also check to see if your flash player is updated to the latest version.

Comment: ok thanks...i just have my localhost open in safari and it's not displaying...i'm not able to use safari because of the proxy settings on my work computer

Comment: Lame proxies, glad you were able to figure out why.  Good luck and happy coding...